# Comparison operator to be used in std::lower_bound

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stl-algorithm

My compiler refuse to compile this simple code:

```
struct mystruct{
    int x;
    bool operator<(const mystruct& y) const{ return x < y.x; }
};


std::map<mystruct, int> test;
auto it = std::lower_bound(test.begin(), test.end(), mystruct{2});
```

I'm getting the error

```
error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::less<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const'
```

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677072/c-error-c2893) link, it seems that you just need to define a constant comparison operator which is exactly what I'm doing. Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the value type of your map is `std::pair<const mystruct, int>`, and so `std::lower_bound` is trying to compare `mystruct` with `std::pair<const mystruct, int>`. And there is no operator defined for that.

You shouldn't be using `std::lower_bound` on a `std::map` anyway. It will work in O(n) because a map does not have random-access iterators. `std::map` has its own `lower_bound` member function which will take advantage of the tree structure to give you the result in O(log n).

```
auto it = test.lower_bound(mystruct{2});
```